# Initialize tooltip for Highcharts chart rendered in server

Tags: highcharts

I am using Highcharts, however for security reason I have to render chart in server and display the output (SVG) directly in browser as an image. Everything is working fine except tooltip. Is there anyway tooltip can be initialized later in Highcharts for pre-rendered chart?

Comment: Yes it is my own server. I am using PhantomJS.

Comment: In highcharts we use javascript to trigger any actions like tooltip etc. When you render chart as SVG only (by phantomJS) there is no javascript / events so tooltip cannot be displayed.

Comment: I understand in PhantomJS there are no events. However, if I display that same generated SVG in browser later is there anyway that I can bind the events and trigger the tooltip display.